# Conditional String Replacement in Linux

Tags: shell, unix, text, sed, command

I have a massive (100M line) file which I need to edit on linux before uploading to our DB. It is a pipe-delimited file and takes the following format at the moment:

```
a|b|c|d
e|f|g|h
  ijkl
  mn
o|p|q|r
s|t|u|v
```

I would like to change it to this format:

```
a|b|c|d
e|f|g|h  ijkl  mn
o|p|q|r
s|t|u|v
```

I've been trying to it up using Regex and grep/sed/tr but I am new to shell and incredibly stuck.

Does anyone have any suggestions? It would really be a great help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This awk one-liner works for the given example:

```
awk -F'|' '{printf "%s%s", (NF==4&&NR>1?RS:""),$0}END{print ""}' file
```

If we test:

```
kent$  cat f
a|b|c|d
e|f|g|h
  ijkl
  mn
o|p|q|r
s|t|u|v

kent$  awk -F'|' '{printf "%s%s", (NF==4&&NR>1?RS:""),$0}END{print ""}' f
a|b|c|d
e|f|g|h  ijkl  mn
o|p|q|r
s|t|u|v
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to append to the *previous* line if the *current* line has fewer than the expected number of fields:

```
awk -F '|' -v n=4 '
    NF != n {prev = prev $0; next} 
    prev {print prev} 
    {prev = $0} 
    END {print prev}
' file
```

```
a|b|c|d
e|f|g|h  ijkl  mn
o|p|q|r
s|t|u|v
```

An alternate way to look at it is to reverse the file and remember stuff that doesn't have the right number of fields:

```
tac file |
 awk -F'|' -v n=4 'NF != n {s = $0 " " s; next} {print $0, s; s = ""}' |
 tac
```